# Access public dropbox files (via shared link) without user authentication

Tags: json, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to integrate Dropbox into my web application in the following way:

1. Users can enter a [Dropbox Share Link](https://www.dropbox.com/help/20/en), i.e. a Dropbox folder that can be accessed by anyone, even without a dropbox account.
2. My application then grabs the images from the folder and displays them to all users of my application.

Now as far as I can tell, the Dropbox API doesn't allow this **without sending the user through a full-blown OAuth process**. But since the shared link is public anyway, I don't need (and don't want) access to the users Dropbox account.

Is there a way to access a shared link in a programmatic way (without parsing the DOM or similar hacks)? Maybe there is a query parameter on the shared link to retrieve the contents as JSON? If it exists, I didn't find any docs about it.

Surely I'm not the first one to try this, so please share your solutions!

Comment: Would you at least mind to tell me why this question deserves a downvote? Some SO users really have no manners...

Comment: I'd guess it's because similar questions exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764072/retrieve-contents-of-a-public-dropbox-folder but have an upvote on the house from me. Interested to know the answer to this myself as it goes.

Comment: this question is better directed at dropbox support... https://www.dropbox.com/support/s/94/5200125/c/3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no programmatic way to list folder contents from a share link. If you have a share link for a specific file, then you can convert the domain from `www.dropbox.com` to `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`, but this trick doesn't work on folders.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. Maybe I stick with Flickr then.